# PHP - SimpleXML Using Variables Created From Objects Made in ForEach Loop

Tags: php, variables, object, foreach, simplexml

I am trying to develop a navigation breadcrumb system for my new website.
My page uses SimpleXML to retrieve it's file name and page information from an xml database.

I am recieving php error for the **preg_replace();** function in the last code block: *Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/content/85/8762385/html/joelsdesign/movies/we-are-hiring.php on line 21*

In the head of the document, there is
    **$dom = simplexml_load_file('pages.xml');**

This is the contents of my xml file: http://joelsdesign.info/movies/scores.xml

My navigation menu is 'required' and the require statement is stored in my variable called **$nav**

```
foreach ($dom->page as $page) {
    $title = $page->title;
    $file = $page->file;
    $nav = file_get_contents('require/nav.php');
    $nav = preg_replace("<li><a href=\"".$file."\">".$title."</a></li>", "<li class="current"><a href=\"".$file."\">".$title."</a></li>", $nav);
}
```

Comment: As a matter of taste I like being pedantic about my questions and always research the error messages I get. Most of the times this leads me to the main 4-5 causes of those errors being displayed. Because of this I end up answering most of my own questions before I even post them.

Answer (score 0):

The quotes around the word `current` were not escaped:

```
$nav = preg_replace("<li><a href=\"".$file."\">".$title."</a></li>", "<li class=\"current\"><a href=\"".$file."\">".$title."</a></li>", $nav);
```

Also you shouldn't be using preg_replace without using a regex. You should be using str_replace.

If you actually needed preg_replace you would have written a regex - Regular Expression - that needs to start with a delimiter most often the forward slash `/`. Hence the second error is created by the fact that `<` is not a known delimiter for a regex.

Comment: that works, but a second level error is displayed saying that: 'Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier '<''

Comment: I've updated my answer with info on the second level error. Please write the contents of your comment in the question so others can see why my answer needed to contain those specifications.